# iOS - print javascript as text in uiwebview not to execute

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, uiwebview

`><svg/onload=alert(document.domain)>` i want to print this text in uiwebview. Right now it gives me alert "myapplication.app" and not showing any text.

To load html string i am using `[webView loadHTMLString:HtmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];` this code.

Basically i want to print javascripts as text in `UIWebView` and don't want them to get execute.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i could not find any solution for this. The only reason i was using `UIWebview` is to show html links. But as `UITextview` also can show links i changes element from `UIWebview` to `UITextview`. Which solve the issue of executing `javascript` text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by replacing `<svg/onload=alert(document.domain)>` with a string in your `HtmlString`.

```
HtmlString = [HtmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<svg/onload=alert(document.domain)>" withString:@"\"<svg/onload=alert(document.domain)>\""];
```

Comment: that is just a demo string. What if i have this kind of multiple string? and print them as a text.

Comment: I can't think of an alternative solution right now, but you could generalize that solution by making a variadic method that takes an html string and the strings that you want them to be displayed as strings.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it will help you or that you find a better solution.